# how to display associated models in views in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, models

This is probably a n00b question. I have CitiesUser model:

`class CitiesUser < ActiveRecord::Base {
    belongs_to :city
    belongs_to :user
}`

In the controller I do this:

`def index      {
    @cities_users = CitiesUser.find(:all,
            :conditions => { :user_id => session[:user][:id] },
            :include => [:city])`

and in the view this:

`<%= @cities_users.inspect %>`

Now, I don't see associated model City anywhere. How do I iterate in my view over Cities that are attached to CitiesUser?

My WEBRick says:

`CitiesUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "cities_users".* FROM "cities_users" WHERE "cities_users"."user_id" = 1`

`City Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE ("cities"."id" IN (5,3))`

So the association is being loaded, right? Which variable is it stored in, or how to I put it inside my CitiesUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through the city association.

```
<%= @cities_users.map{ |cu| cu.city.name }.sort.join(', ') %>
```

However, if the cities_user table is basically [ :user_id, :city_id ], then you have no need for the CitiesUser model at all. Instead your models should look like:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cities
  ...
end
```

In your controller, just make sure you have the User record (many auth schemes make this avaiable via a `current_user` method:

```
@user = current_user
@user ||= User.find session[:user][:id]
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= @user.cities.map { |c| c.name }.sort.join(', ') %>
```

Comment: Thanks, the first line is what I was looking for! As a note, the table cities_users has date, name, and descr so it`s not a standard habtm.

Comment: In that case, I'd go with `has_many :through` and still use AR associations instead of querying against the cities_users table.